# IOS Background reopen: FIRESTORE (7.6.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: AsyncQueue is already failed: transaction

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

#### Describe your environment

- Operating System version: IOS 13.3
- Browser version: Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView 13.3
- Firebase SDK version: 7.6.2
- Firebase Product: database (firestore)

#### Describe the problem

Steps to reproduce:

Ionic cordova app using Firestore. Works very well under normal situations.
When opening through notification and it's a cold app start, also no problems.
**But only when the app is in the background and reopened through a notification tap, firebase will throw a lot of errors and stop working**:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.6.2): FIRESTORE (7.6.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: AsyncQueue is already failed: transaction@[native code]

Relevant Code:

(Cannot reproduce this on stackblitz as it is on device.)
Simplified use:

```js
constructor(public storage: AngularFireStorage,
                public auth: AuthService,
                private afs: AngularFirestore,
                private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {
}

private loadData() {
...
this.itemList= this.afs.collection('users').doc(uid).collection<ItemList>('items').valueChanges({ idField: 'item' });
...
}
```

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="itemList| async as item; else loadingOrError">
```

Posted as issue, but thought to ask here as well.
I've seen a similar issue ([Ionic 4 IOS FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: AsyncQueue is already failed: An internal error was encountered in the Indexed Database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443547/ionic-4-ios-firestore-internal-assertion-failed-asyncqueue-is-already-failed-a)) which is marked as solved but only a mediocre errorhandling has been suggested there.

Comment: I don't know why this is flagged as off topic, but got the same error. Did you find something?

Comment: Bug has been confirmed by the dev team and they are looking for a solution: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2581#issuecomment-583137833